# Display urdu text on browser

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I am trying to use Nastaliq Unicode NFL and the Jameel Noori Nastaleeq fonts for displaying text in Urdu in the browsers. But it isn't displaying properly in any of the browsers.

Please suggest a mechanism through which I can display the text in the same format as is displayed in the below site:

http://www.urdupoint.com/

Thanks,
Waq

Answer (score 4):

here is the code for that font-family:

http://cdn.urdupoint.com/daily/font-styles/nafees_web_naskhshipped.eot

Now, you can use: `@font-face` to apply this to use own website.

You should have seen this code in the website's HTML Inspector. It was just there at the end of the code.

For `@font-face`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: Thank you, But even after downloading this font from the above link I am not able to display the Urdu text properly in the browser. It's still showing the same as was before. Here is the code that I wrote:

Comment: <style>  
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(nafees_web_naskhshipped.eot);
}
div
{
font-family:myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
وہ ہر چند چاہیں گے کہ آگ سے نکل جائیں مگر اس سے نہیں نکل سکیں گے اور ان کیلئے ہمیشہ کا عذاب ہے۔ اور چوری کرنے والا مرد اور چوری کرنے والی عورت ان کا ایک ایک ہاتھ کاٹ دو ، یہ ان کے کرتوتوں کی سزا اور اللہ کی طرف سے عبرت کے 

طور پر ہے اور اللہ زبردست ہے صاحب حکمت ہے۔ پھر جو شخص گناہ کے بعد توبہ کرلے اور نیکو کار ہو جائے تو اللہ اسکو معاف کردے گا، کچھ شک نہیں کہ اللہ بڑا بخشنے والا ہے بڑا مہربان ہے۔
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

From Notepad++ you can simply write Urdu just like English

`<span style="font-size:13px;padding-left:53px; font-family:Nafees Nastaleeq;"><i> براے مہربانی اپنی باری کا انتظار کریں </i></span>`

To add other font family, 
See this link

http://font.urduweb.org/

Answer (score 0):

Add Jameel Nooriee Css Font Family in css. Then Try it

```css
.urduh {
 font-family: Jameel Noori Nastaleeq;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<p class="urduh" >زندگی میں بہت سی پریشانیان آ سکتی ہیں</p>

</body>
</html>
```